# Removing output/generated HTML code in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp, output, generated

< ![CDATA[ ]]> code gets wrapped inside a  tag, which shows up on the generated HTML page. This CDATA then turns off the style tags inside it.

Example:

```
<style>
<![CDATA[
div { border: 1px solid red; }
]]>
</style>
```

Anyone know how to remove < ![CDATA[ ]]> code in JSP? The < ![CDATA[ ]]> code is not present in the JSP, but gets added only in output.

Comment: what is the IDE used?

Comment: It's varied here, but I use Komodo.

Comment: `<![CDATA[` implies you have it configured somewhere to output as XML/XHTML rather than just HTML.

Comment: The parser app is most likely the culprit. With that said, the easiest fix on my end would be to fix for this one .jsp by sniffing out CDATA, but I'm not sure if that's even possible?